# Why does this code not write to the external txt document?

Tags: python, text, external, document

I am pretty new to Python, and I am making a script to write some text to an external text document, but it isn't working Can anyone help?

```
with open("NameDatabase.txt", "a") as txtDoc:
    txtDoc.write('ID[' + num + ']' + ' ' + firstName + '\n')
    txtDoc.close()
```

This is meant to print out a couple variables, `firstName` and `num`, to a file called `NameDatabase.txt`, but it just does nothing (and I triple checked that all the variables and the text file are named correctly).

Comment: No need to `close()` since `with` means you are inside the context and it will close automatically after writing.

Comment: it should work even with explicit `close()`

Comment: Sounds like `NameDatabase.txt` just isn't where you expect it to be. Try specifying the absolute path rather than relying on a relative one.

Answer (score 0):

```
num=23
firstName="Kayden"
with open("NameDatabase.txt", "a") as txtDoc:
    txtDoc.write('ID[' + str(num) + ']' + ' ' + firstName + '\n')
    txtDoc.close()
```

I replaced num with str(num) to concatenate with string and its working fine for me.

Comment: This is more like a comment and less an answer.